# fragment does not have class attribute in Xamarin Android. Gives an error "Class attribute not declared":

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.android

I am trying to use Google maps using Xamerien Android. I have added below code in my Layout.

[axml code look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvhXQ.png)

But for the fragment, it says Class attribute not declared. Could someone please help me with this. I am struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Google Maps Android API docs, you have to set the `android:name` attribute as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Please refer to the docs here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#add_a_fragment